# Mistake in the Feynman Lectures Volume 1 Ch. 18-2 - Rotation of a rigrid body

Tags: rotational-kinematics

I just read http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_18.html#Ch18-S2

In my opinion, in this chapter the equations 18.6 and 18.7 are wrong. Have a look at the Picture http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_18.html#Ch18-F1 .

> If $OP$ is called $r$, then the length $PQ$ is $rΔθ$, because of the way angles are defined. The change in $x$, then, is simply the projection of $rΔθ$ in the $x$-direction: $$\Delta x=-PQ\sin\theta=-r\,\Delta\theta\cdot(y/r)=-y\,\Delta\theta$$

That is equation 18.6. *It is wrong because $\Delta\theta$ doesn't mean that $\theta_{Q}-\theta_{P}$ is infinitesimally small and equation 18.6 is only valid for infinitesimally small $\Delta\theta$.*

An example is: I take $P$ to be $(1|0)$ and $Q$ to be $(0|1)$ than $\Delta x$ is $-1$ but calculated using equation 18.6 it should have been $-y\Delta\theta=(-1)(\pi /2)\approx -1,57$, which is wrong.

In the equations $d\theta$ should have be used instead of $\Delta\theta$.

**Is my reasoning correct?**

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. But Feynman does mean a small rotation. If not infinitesimal, then at least small enough that the error is less than the accuracy of your measurement.

Comment: Moreover, I think that this is only wrong if you're trying to be pedantic. The $\Delta$ vs. $d$ notation issue is often very minor as it is clear from the context what is meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book says "If at a moment Δt later the angle of the whole object has turned through Δθ..." A "moment" in this context is meant to convey a vanishingly short period of time, not an indefinitely long one, which means that Δθ is taken to be a vanishingly small angle. Furthermore, Feynman (and anyone else) is free to use whatever notations they like; there is no "law" that dictates dθ has to be used in this context.

Comment: Your signature should go in your user's profile. And how did you find this question so fast?